# Excel Find multiples values for single adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have a similar spreadsheet structured as the shared image.  Column A has names listed, sometimes multiple times.  I need to pick out those names where the adjacent value is Unavailable all times.  I can't figure out what function to use.  Should I use Vlookup? Uniques?

So in this example.  Only Spencer should fit the criteria.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you for your time.

Comment: So the output would be `Spencer` just the name?  Also what if two or more fit that example?  What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Office 365.
But I have 1000 rows of names to go through.

Comment: You did not answer what specifically the output should look like. ie, do you want them all in one cell delimited, or a list (one name per cell), or something else entirely.

Comment: Im looking to do one name per cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FILTER() with COUNTIFS as the criteria.  We use UNIQUE because duplicates would be returned

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9)=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,"Unavailable"),""))
```

This will spill a list, so make sure the cells below where you put the formula are empty.

Comment: Scott, some parenthesis issue has the formula, I guess this is the correct one: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9)=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,"Unavailable"),""))`

Comment: @DavidLeal thanks, it was missing the `)` after the  second countifs.

Answer (score 3):

To output the names, that are not available you can use this formula:

```
=LET(uNames,UNIQUE(data[Name]),
isAvailable,BYROW(uNames,LAMBDA(n,COUNTIFS(data[Name],n,data[Value],"<>Unavailable"))),
FILTER(uNames,isAvailable=0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My two cents; being under the impression that, when looking at the values, one could assume you'd like to pull names where 'value == 0'. If true, then you could try:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,SUMIF(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9)=0,""))
```

If my assumption does not hold true, you could use `COUNTIFS()` and count the values that do *not* have any value other than 'Unavailable':

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,"<>Unavailable")=0,""))
```